# Two worksheet matching in excel

Tags: excel-formula

my excel contains two sheets 1st sheet column A and second sheet column A are same matter but not order I want to display in the first sheet that is column A1 contain in sheet 2 column a, then display in sheet 1 sheet to b cell

Comment: your question is incomprehensible. I realize that English is not your first language, but if you use some punctuation and maybe a web translation like Google Translate, then it might be possible to understand what you are asking.

Comment: kindly insert image in the question too.  enter image description here][1]